# Is there a theory of induced representations for semigroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory

Given a semigroup $G$, a subgroup $H\subseteq G$ (not merely a subsemigroup) and a representation $\rho: H\rightarrow GL(V)$ for some vector space $V$, is there a canonical definition of an induced representation on some vector space $V^\prime$ containing $V$? 
Is there even a well developed representation theory of semigroups? 
If so, please give me references.

(I encountered this question while working on my master's thesis, which includes a generalization/extension of certain Hecke operators on vector valued modular forms.)

Thanks in advance,
mathmax

Edit: Corrected typo; of course, $\rho$ has to be a representation of $H$ not of $G$

Comment: Do you mean for $\rho$ to be a representation of $H$?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  A representation $V$ of a semigroup $G$ is the same as a module over the rng (ring without unit) $k[G]$.  If $H \subset G$ then we get a map of rngs $k[H] \to k[G]$.  Then the role of the induced representation is played by $k[G] \otimes_{k[H]} V$.

If $G,H$ are groups then this is the same as the usual induction.  And it satsifies the relevant universal property:  An $H$-equivariant map from $V$ to a $G$ module $W$ is the same as a $G$-map from $k[G]\otimes_{k[H]} V \to W$.

I'd suggest looking for references that talk about modules over nonunital associative algebras (another name for these rngs, except ones that contain a field).

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a book on the representation theory of monoids. The latest version is http://www.sci.ccny.cuny.edu/~benjamin/monoidrep.pdf

You will see that there is a more subtle way to induce representations of a monoid from its maximal subgroups than the way suggested by Phil which is essential for constructing the simple modules.